# Is it possible to change table view's cells dynamically by using a segmented control?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `view controller` with a `segmented control` and a `table view` inside of it. I know that it is possible to change the content of the cells in that `table view` by using a `segmented control` (by keeping these cells the same).

But what if the layout of cells differ, like there are different subviews in their `content view` or there are the same subviews but they are positioned differently, with different constraints? Is it possible to somehow use the same table view and just change cells that it uses, or should I use another table view by animating it on and off of the screen(if so, I still have to use the same `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods, right?)?

If you know the answer and the best approach for doing this, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes its is possible. you can create many cells on your table view with different identifier and call them as per your requirement

Comment: @MuseerAnsari, so, when I register one type of cells and later, above that, I register another one, the first one automatically gets replaced, right?

Comment: what do you mean by structure? just the cell layout or also the data you want to show?

Comment: i don't get your comment exactly but. call identifier in `cellForRowAtIndex method` as per your requirement

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs, I mean the layout

Comment: as for the layout the best approach is what Musser Ansari is pointed out for you

Comment: @MuseerAnsari, I got it. I just wanted to know whether, in that case, the old  cells are still in the view hierarchy of the `table view` (under the new ones) or they are replaced and they are no more in the view hierarchy.

Comment: they get replaced. because you are reloading the table view.

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs, Ok. I will use that approach. Thank you )

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan you can register as many types of cells as you like.  You just dequeue the ones you want in the cellForRowAtIndex method.  If you want to change from one type of cell to another just use reloadData to force the table view to reload and in the cellForRowAtIndex method chose which cell to dequeue based on the segmented control.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth, thank you for explanation :)